# Ios xcode bottom bar is always tab items

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I have this stucture:

Tab Bar -> Navigation -> Table View -> View

at the end, in the last `View` i need to have new bottom bar, but it always shows me Tab Bar..

I set bottom item on last `View` to "Podeli":
[image]

now on this image you can see simulator on that last `View`:
[image]

There are still those 3 tab bar items..
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide your tab bar controller's tab bar. The other bar is likely behind it.

Comment: How to do that and on which controller?

Comment: Where do you want to see the other bottom bar & not the tab bar?

Comment: In the last `View`(`Ad Detail View Controller`) on screenshot. when i try `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true` on `viewDidLoad` it hides me all bottom bars.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one - http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-how-to-hide-tab-bar-navigation-controller/

There is a property named “hidesBottomBarWhenPushed” in UIViewController. It’s a Boolean value indicating whether the toolbar at the bottom of the screen is hidden. When it’s set to YES, the tab bar will be hidden when the view controller is pushed on to a navigation controller.

Comment: When i do this, it hides tabbar, but there is no bottom bar with this button item "Podeli" :/